# Install Samba 3.0.24 on Ubuntu Server 10.04 from Source

Tags: 10.04, networking, server, samba, antivirus

Has anyone had any luck compiling and installing Samba 3.0.24 on Ubuntu 10.04?  I'm trying to set up realtime virus scanning on Samba shares (ClamAV) using the legacy version of Samba as it is the latest release supported by samba-vscan-0.3.6b.  I'm no expert at this but I think I have all of the dependencies covered and I'm following the documentation with the source code but I'm getting errors as if there is a problem with the source code.

I downloaded the source directly from http://ftp.samba.org/pub/samba/stable/samba-3.0.24.tar.gz

After running *./configure* and *make*, I get the following error.

```
Compiling client/mount.cifs.c
client/mount.cifs.c: In function ‘main’:
client/mount.cifs.c:1068: error: ‘PATH_MAX’ undeclared (first use in this function)
client/mount.cifs.c:1068: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
client/mount.cifs.c:1068: error: for each function it appears in.)
make: *** [client/mount.cifs.o] Error 1
```

You can view the full output log [here](http://www.nilpo.com/pub/examples/putty.log).

Can anyone help me get this installed or suggest another means of implementing realtime virus scanning on Samba shares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the source file `client/mount.cifs.c` and add

```
#ifndef PATH_MAX
#define PATH_MAX 256
#endif
```

I added it under

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif
```

not sure if it matters, but that made that error go away and finish making.

Note. I found references to that value beeing 256 and others of it beeing 1024, unsure of what the difference is, i tried 256 and it installed

Comment: Brilliant!  That did it.  I was able to make my way through the install.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped :)

Comment: Note that there are various serious open security issues in 3.0.24, as Samba 3.0 is no longer receiving security fixes.